# Can't handle form data sent with multiple files in laravel controller

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

So I have a input with "multiple" files and I'm passing this to a form Data but in my Controller I only can access to $_POST['Files']

So in my index.file I'm sending files through ajax request with form data,

```
var fileList=tr.children[29].children[0].files;

var fd2 = new FormData();
fd2.append('Files',filesArray);
fd2.append('_token',"{{ csrf_token() }}"); 

$.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            type: "POST",
            url:"{{ route('SaveFileInfo') }}",
            data:fd2,
            dataType:'multipart/form-data',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data){
                alert('sucess');
            },
            error:function(err){
                   console.log("error---> ", err);
            }
        });
```

In my controller,

```
public function saveFileInfo(Request $request) {

$fileList=$_POST['Files'];

var_dump($fileList);

foreach($fileList as $file){
    print_r($file);
}
```

I'm trying to access to my [object File List] and iterate it like a array and save all info of the files in a table (file name, size, mime-type)...

The problem is I don't know hot to manage this kind of object.. can i covnert it to array? I've tried do convert to array in javascript side like,

```
var filesArray = JSON.stringify(Object.keys(fileList).map(i => fileList[i]));
```

but this returns

```
[{},{}]
```

Any idea of how to handle this in server side (laravel) ?

Comment: You should not be using `$_POST` in Laravel; the `Request $request` object exists for a reason, so use it: `$request->file('Files')`

Comment: it returns null, if I pass $request->input('File') it returns a string pass..

Comment: i would start with dd($request->all()) and see what I am receiving in the POST data.

Comment: in headers I have in my form data Files: [object FileList] and in Preview array:2 [
  "Files" => "[object FileList]"
  "_token" => odkodkdo
]